# Building fail issue with xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

hi im try to build my project with xcode but it show me that issue.

The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. Unable to launch com.kt.ios.narletest because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.

how can i solve it?

Comment: Did you check your signature or signing configurations?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213319/xcode-error-launching-watchkit-extension) may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this - the solution for me was to add my apps to the list of trusted apps on my device:

Go to your iPhone Settings > General > VPN & Device Management and "trust" apps created by yourself as developer, including test apps